# Allow voting on comments from Review interface

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, review

I'm still becoming increasingly confused as to why we can't do or see certain things (really, just about anything except for *answer* a question) from the Review interface.

Today, it's comment voting.  I came across a question in the close queue where another person had already left a comment that clearly described why the question should be closed.  Sometimes, I'll come across other questions where a commenter has also clearly stated what can be done to improve this question so that it will either not be closed or will be a good candidate for getting re-opened.  Often times, in either case, the thread *is* still worth my close vote because it is either off-topic, low quality, or missing out on some other SE criteria, and it does not contain enough detail for me to feel confident that I can edit it into a *good* question that is still valuable to its original author.

I personally feel that, in most cases, it is our *responsibility* to the question author to give them feedback if we are going to down-vote or vote-to-close their question.  Sometimes, the feedback is clear enough in the close reason but this is only visible after the final vote - and even then, only the option selected by the majority is shown.  For instances where I'm giving a down-vote, or I'm one of the first-through-fourth people voting to close, the comment space is my only real option for giving feedback to the author.  Regardless, I feel that providing feedback to the author is essential in helping them to learn how to write better questions, write questions that better fit the StackExchange model, and get answers that are both useful to them and the community.

However, in cases where another person's comment already clearly and thoroughly relates my concerns regarding the post, it's often preferable that I up-vote the existing comment instead of leaving my own, redundant comment to clutter up the thread.  This is not currently an option from within the Review interface.  Interestingly enough, I'm allowed to leave a comment but I'm not allowed to vote on existing comments.

If I want to vote on an existing comment, I need to follow one of two processes - the choice between which is pretty much determined by the first step in each:

- *Remember that the Review interface will immediately leave the question when I choose an action option.*
- *Open one of the links to the question in a new, background tab in my browser.*
- Choose my action for the question.

  - If necessary, choose the reason for my action.
  - If necessary, select other options (i.e.: duplicate question) to complete the action.
- *Switch to the question's tab.*
- Vote on the comment.
- *Close the question's tab and go back to reviewing, or doing whatever else I was going to do.*

OR

- *Forget that the Review interface will immediately leave the question when I choose an action option.*
- Choose my action for the question.

  - If necessary, choose the reason for my action.
  - If necessary, select other options (i.e.: duplicate question) to complete the action.
- *Open a new browser tab with the main site interface.*
- *Search for and open the question.*
- Vote on the comment.
- *Close the question's tab and go back to reviewing, or doing whatever else I was going to do.*

Each of these workflows has four steps (italicized), plus associated page loading times, that I would not need to go through if the option to vote on a comment was simply included in the Review interface.  So, for the sake of our time and sanity - the savings of which, I believe, is the primary goal of this interface in the first place - please add or restore this functionality.

Comment: +1! Specifically, allowing comment upvotes in the Review Close Votes section would be a great way to help (new) users understand why a question was closed and what they can do to ask better questions.

Comment: @minitech Finding ways to boost your "meta presence" before the elections? ;)

Comment: @LoremIpsum: No, but I did just start using the other review queues again :D

Comment: I agree voting on comments should be allowed from the close votes queue. But the title of this feature-request is a bit misleading, at at least one of the review queues does allow that (can't remember which one).

Comment: Well, I'm doing Ctrl+LeftClick combination very often.

Comment: This is a year old and there has been little response. I see no reason to disallow comment voting while in the close review.

Answer (score 10):

+1, this seems like it should be a no-brainer for the reasons very well outlined in the question.  I note that many people seem to have agreed with the sentiment.  Strangely, not much seems to have happened in the past year.  Let me add a couple more points in favor:

- You can upvote comments in other review queues, such as **First Posts**.
- In the comments on the duplicate question, [Allow comment upvoting in review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149318/allow-comment-upvoting-in-review?lq=1), it is noted that you *can* upvote comments in the **Close Votes** queue if you first click *show more comments*.  However, clicking, e.g., *add comment* will not enable comment upvoting, so there need to be enough comments for the *show more comments* to appear to use this hack.  This does seem like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I added a bounty to bring attention to this.

It seems like a really obvious thing to implement given functionality already exists in other review queues.

1. This seems such a useful thing. Right now, you can close questions in the queue without any interaction other than a CV
2. Often people will post comments which are exactly why I want to close questions. Right now, you have to open the question in a new tab
3. You can already add comments anyways, it only seems natural to be able to upvote other comments

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that deleting and flagging comments should be enabled, too, given sufficient privilege. I'm already reviewing the question, why am I not allowed to clean up the comment section at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (though I'm not sure when it has been implemented exactly); it's possible to upvote (and flag) comments in all review queues except for the Suggested Edits, where comments are always hidden. Upvoting comments counts as an 'action' for the First Posts and Late Answers queues, i.e. the <kbd>Done</kbd> button will be activated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why the comment voting / flagging should be disabled anywhere.

Everywhere where there is a comment it should be also allowed to vote the comment.

Seems like a bug to me since if I navigate to the question directly it is possible to vote the comments...