# Allow comment upvoting in review

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, comment-voting

I was reviewing close votes when I noticed it is impossible to upvote comments of a flagged question.

When a comment states why the reason the question is being closed I think it's nice to upvote it. Currently one must open the question in another tab/window to be able to upvote a comment, which is inconvenient. Would it be possible to do it directly from the Review interface?

**UPDATE**

Like @Flimm said, it is possible to upvote comments after clicking the "show more comments". So in my opinion it is definitely a bug that it is not possible to do it at first.

Answer (score 6):

It would be great if that option is there.

But I don't think Stack Exchange team will implement this. Because not all comments can be good or bad. We are reviewing question and not that comment. Your concentration should be towards reviewing that flagged question. And if you want to up-vote comment then need to open the question in another tab/window to be able to up-vote a comment.

Comment: I had the exact thought actually. But then why can you add a comment from the review page?

Comment: Comment is action included in review of question. That's why you can comment in reviewing. And you are able to view comments of other people because you can get idea about OP's conversation and suggestion already given to OP.

Comment: What if the comment I want to give is the exact same one someone else has already given? It seems logical that I should upvote that comment instead of posting a duplicate comment.

Comment: In right side, there is link of post, if you want to up vote or flag. By the way you are reviewing post not comments. If you really like comment then anyways you can go to resource. Current review queues are specific to review type. @Flimm

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I disagree, and I think it's a bug, not a deliberate feature. You can add a comment, and you can even upvote comments if you click "show more comments" first.

Comment: Note that if there aren't enough comments for the "show more comments" to appear, you cannot use this hack; eg, the "add comment" does not provide this feature.