# Why can't I flag comments when reviewing close votes?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, review, flags

I understand that, since questions with close votes show up to many people, voting is disabled. Otherwise, would get way too much (negative) rep that they only get because of the close vote.

However, how does this reason for locking votes apply on **flagging comments**? The faster offensive comments get removed, the better, not?

Can someone explain this to me? Or, if not, could this be changed?

Comment: Related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146783/205264) but different (not?) as this is about _flagging_ and not about _voting_.