# Review Close Votes queue not allowing vote to post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, voting

[Related post for upvote on comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146783/allow-voting-on-comments-from-review-interface)

While reviewing close-votes queue I found some good question, which deserves upvote but the interface not allowed me to vote from that screen. Now I have to open the question in new tab to vote.

> [image: review queue]

I think we need to allow voting on this screen so it does not required two steps to complete it.

#### EDIT

This can encourage or allow a chance to vote to a questions as describe here [why aren't people voting for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Comment: Perhaps this is a measurement to prevent reviewers down-voting questions blindly?

Comment: We *don't* discourage the use of down-votes if you're voting to close. We just encourage you to focus when you're reviewing vs. viewing questions normally.