# Comment upvotes and flags don't work when reviewing on mobile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, review, mobile-safari

Normally, when I browse a site in desktop mode on my iPhone, I can tap a comment and the upvote and flag options will appear:

[image]

However, this doesn't work when reviewing from mobile. I can tap or long-press whatever I want, but the upvote/flag options won't appear.

This is not really a duplicate of [Allow voting on comments from Review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146783/allow-voting-on-comments-from-review-interface); that's simply a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) which has never been updated to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (so I do understand the close votes). For proof, see the screenshot below:

[image]

(and flagging is possible as well, by the way)

Comment: That's because it's not possible, regardless of mobile or not. (i.e. not a bug, there's already request asking to add this feature.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'm sitting here, in the close queue, with all userscripts turned off, and comment upvotes and flags are clearly accessible to me. What's going on?

Comment: @Nathan looks like they never updated that feature request when doing it. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the new design is going to solve this; on this site, I'm able to upvote (at least) in the Close Vote review queue after tapping the comment:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this was fixed in the redesign, or if it got fixed somewhere else along the way - but I can't make this happen now. FWIW, you probably already know this but the full functionality isn't there unless you're using the full site theme - even though the rest of review looks more or less the same regardless of whether you have the mobile or full theme active.