# Upvoting comments from review queues often fails because t.state is null

Tags: bug, review, action-buttons

When I try to upvote comments on review items from various queues network-wide, sometimes it works, but sometimes it fails. When it fails, a numbers sign `#` gets appended to the end of the review item's URL, and the upvote fails to register on the comment. If the page has been scrolled down, the scrollbar will also snap back up to the top position.

I've observed this happening with Firefox on Windows 11. The issue is reproducible on the Stack Overflow Triage and First Questions queues, and the ELL First Questions queue, so I would guess it affects **all** queues.

Could this issue be related to the recent changes to button styling described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updated-styling-for-button-groups?cb=1)? (The linked question is currently `Featured` on MSE.) This seems likely, because it is possible to select the comment upvote buttons using the 'tab' key, per @Fabio's comment under the announcement.

---

**ERROR MESSAGE:** With Developer Tools enabled, the button press causes this error (not warning) to be logged to the console:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: t.state is null
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1
    <anonymous> https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35819260#:859
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 6
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 2
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    t https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 3
    onreadystatechange https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    d https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    u https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    <anonymous> https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35819260#:858
    jQuery 3
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 3
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 2
    c https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    t https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 3
    onreadystatechange https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    d https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    u https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    p https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    s https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    h https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    init https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=30dc0e2fbcff:1
    jQuery 8
        fire
        fireWith
        ready
        completed
        promise
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
```

While I'm aware this question is very similar to [a previous feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146783/allow-voting-on-comments-from-review-interface), it seems the feature request was resolved some time ago as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and so the current issue is **not** "by design." (Upvoting comments from *any* review queue seems to have worked reliably until somewhere around yesterday [?])

Comment: Reloading the page seems to fix the problem

Comment: Since triage is SO only - I feel like this would be a better fit for MSO?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the issue affected anything else (I haven't attempted to reproduce it in any other queues yet), but assumed an issue like this wouldn't be site-specific. If it is, should I delete this question and re-ask it there instead?

Comment: OK, now the same thing just happened in the First Questions queue too (also on SO).

Comment: Just reproduced it on ELL First Questions queue - it looks like it is network-wide

Comment: Aha, those little triangles are selectable via the 'tab' key... could the issue be related to this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updated-styling-for-button-groups If so I'd imagine it'll be fixed soon

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Triage is on Physics too, so this is indeed related to multiple sites and thus on-topic.

Comment: Could you update the broader issue on the main post please? Comments are just so easily overlooked.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'll do that now :)

Comment: It's impacted multiple queue on SO, I made a post on SO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429598/10952503) about this issue